# Id changing variable

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a project where I upload a file and use its path in a shortcode. Right now I've hard-coded the post's ID into my code but I want to make it dynamic so that new posts automatically get the correct shortcode.

```
<?php
global $wpdb; 
$thepost = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = 5574" ) );
echo do_shortcode ('[sgpx gpx="'.'/wp-content/uploads/' . $thepost->meta_value . '"]'); 
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And also there's no point in using a prepared statement if you don't have a parameter to bind to it. Your code might not work because You don't execute the prepared statement.

Comment: The way you retrieve the meta value is a bad idea. This works if a post only has one meta key-value and it happens to come out first using your query. As soon as there are multiple, you might be out of luck and get the wrong row. You should use `get_post_meta($post_id, 'your_meta_key_name_here', true)` to retrieve the value. To create a solution for you, it would be interesting to know where the meta_value actually comes from.

Comment: the piece of code is working but the post id in the code above 5574 and i want it to be so when i make i new post it wil take the id from the uploaded file from that post and puts the id in this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what @Damocles said, you are really setting yourself up for trouble with your current path. Instead, there are built-in WordPress functions that abstract away the database and utilize caching that you are strongly encouraged to use.

```php
// Get the current WordPress post
$the_post = get_post();

//If we have a value (there are cases where this will be empty)
if($the_post){

    // Get the value from the post meta table by the current post's ID
    $the_post_meta = get_post_meta($the_post->ID, 'YOUR_META_KEY_HERE', true);

    // Double-check that we have a value
    if($the_post_meta) {

        // Finally, echo the shortcode
        echo do_shortcode ('[sgpx gpx="'.'/wp-content/uploads/' . $the_post_meta . '"]'); 
    }
}
```

There are several ways to get the current post however [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) is the most common. If you are in a custom loop, however, you might need to adjust accordingly.

To access the meta, use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) which includes some optimizations including use a cache instead of the database.

Although there are definitely exceptions, generally speaking, if you are working with WordPress and you find yourself writing SQL statements, there is almost always a better, safer, faster, etc. way to do it using core functions.

Comment: sorry for the late repons but i need to print the meta_value from a event i tried the code above but couldnt get it to work you hava a idea?

Comment: By "event" do you mean a hook such as a filter or action, or do you mean a custom post type? If you can give more context that would help.

Comment: its a post type its when i make a event it will be a tribe_events post

Comment: So you have two post types, the built-in core `post` or `page` and a CPT from _The Events Calendar_, right? And somehow one is related to another? If so, that relation  holds the post/event ID somewhere, but without seeing your actual setup we can't help you further. You could try dumping `get_postmeta()` on the tribe event or the post to see if that helps you, but might have to make a couple of calls to the meta table to "unwind" the relationship. If, however, the post and the event aren't related, then it is up to you to create a relation so that the "dynamic" part can happen.